# App crashes when reaching 17th uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I'm writing an app that pulls a .txt file from the web, parses it into a 2 dimensional array (essentially. It's actually an NSMutableArray with an NSArray for each element) and then displays each NSArray inside of a UITableView (it loads each NSArray by using sublabels).

Anyways, once I scroll down to the 17th cell (index of 16) the app crashes...

The UITableView should have 483 cells (for testing purposes), but I can't seem to scroll past the 16th cell without it crashing.

**Edit to post code and error:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[[tableView layer] setCornerRadius:3.0];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"]autorelease];
}

NSInteger artistIndex = 1;
NSInteger albumIndex = 3;
NSInteger dateIndex = 6;
NSInteger imageIndex = 5;

// ARTIST
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(59, 11, 244, 13);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:artistIndex];
[cell addSubview:label];

// ALBUM (more like description...
frame = CGRectMake(60, 30, 244, 11);
label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
label.text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:albumIndex];
[cell addSubview:label];

// DATE
frame = CGRectMake(59, 49, 244, 10);
label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
label.text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:dateIndex];
[cell addSubview:label];

// IMAGE
NSString *urlString = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:imageIndex];
NSData *urlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:urlData];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
myImageView.image = myImage;
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(8,9,44,44);
[myImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[myImageView.layer setCornerRadius:3.0];
[[cell contentView] addSubview:myImageView];

[urlData release];
[myImage release];
[myImageView release];
[label release];

return cell;
```

NOTE: I feel like this code is pretty awful... If you guys have any suggestions to clean it up, I'd love to hear it.

And here's the error message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Comment: Minimal examples are useful to understand the problem you have.

Comment: Can you post the log statement you receive when it crashes?

Comment: Looks like something to do with your datasource methods. Which line of this method is causing the crash? I have a feeling your problem lies elsewhere, probably on how you are determining the number of sections or rows on the tableview.

Comment: Rog, you were right. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This won't answer your question, but creating complex cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just isn't good for performance.  If you really need to have a cell like this, consider subclassing `UITableViewCell` so the system can dequeue these as necessary.  Just my opinion.

Comment: You're using arrays with hard-coded indexes to represent tracks? Why not create a model object so you can just access those properties by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have this, and the others like it, backwards.

```
label.text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:artistIndex];
```

Try,

```
label.text = [[musicList.list objectAtIndex:artistIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In my experience, dealing with two-dimensional arrays in objective-c can be sometimes confusing. Especially when working with `UITableViews`.

What makes me have a feeling I am right is this,

```
NSInteger artistIndex = 1;
NSInteger albumIndex = 3;
NSInteger dateIndex = 6;
NSInteger imageIndex = 5;
```

`1 + 3 + 6 + 5 = 15`, and one more, at 16, is the precise index that you are crashing at.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out the file that I was parsing was the error, but without your answer it would have taken me a while to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post code for your `cellForRowAtIndexpath`.
You also need to post the console message you get when the crash occurs.

That being said, it sounds like your operation for rendering the 17th cell is throwing a crash. It could be anything ranging from an EXC_BAD_ACCESS to passing the wrong arguments for an NSLog.

This sounds like a simple error to fix. Post your code and error message.